# Can i get current lock screen background image in iOS?

Tags: ios

Is it possible to get current lock screen background image in iOS?

I see some apps edit lock screen background.
Can anyone tell about this?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: If some apps do it then I suppose that means it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible. Apple does not allow you to do this. Maybe you can try using some private APIs, but you can not submit your App to the official App Store.

Comment: Thanks @falsecrypt, but [this app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pimp-lock-screen-wallpapers/id785009958?mt=8) how works?

Comment: @Mojtaba they don't change/edit the current background image, user creates a new image in this app and sets it later as a background image for the lock screen. Developers are allowed to do that of course.